# iOS9 UIPopoverPresentationController UIModalPresentationPopover display at full width

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, popover

I have a `UIViewController` instance with a `modalPresentationStyle` of `UIModalPresentationPopover`. There are gutters in between the left and right of the popover that I want to remove so that the popover is essentially full-width.

What attributes can I adjust to remove the left and right gutter?

[image: left gutter]

Answer (score 0):

The width of a popover is governed by the `preferredContentSize` of its view controller. If you want total control over the size of a presented view, though, you should use a presented view controller and your own UIPresentationController subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Another property to consider is the `popoverLayoutMargins` of the `UIPopoverPresentationController`.